# How to do a thread dump on Azure App Service?

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, tomcat8

I have an Azure App Service running Tomcat 8.5 and can't seem to figure out how to do a thread dump. jstack is not recognized in the Console nor the DebugConsole.

Comment: Maybe Kudu console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Azure App Service, all popular versions of Java had been installed at the path `D:\Program Files (x86)\Java`. Take version 1.8.0u73 as example, please see the figure below.

[image]

You can command `set PATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;%PATH%` to add Java tools to the environment temporarily via the Kudu console tool. Then, the `jstack` tool is available in the current Kudu session.

Comment: Using your answer, I tried jstack with the pid from the java process in the process explorer tab, but I get a "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF". This might be a problem with my specific application, so could you verify that you can actually do a thread dump this way?

Comment: @DaveyChu Your exception seems to be caused by `jstack` generate a huge content. Please try `jstack -F PID > D:\home\site\out.txt` to output the content to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the previous answer, I created the following bat script (could be powershell, I suppose) that does the job:

```
powershell -Command "get-process java |select -expand id" > pid.txt
set /p id= < pid.txt
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jstack" -F %id% > out.txt
```

It uses the java version that you're using in your app (JAVA_HOME) and doesn't require any input from you. It's simple and does the trick. Just create a bat file in your wwwroot, for example, and run it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for Windows Apps on Azure App Service, this can be easily done by going to **Azure Portal** -> **Diagnose and Solve problems** blade -> **Diagnostic Tools** and then choosing Collect Java Thread dump from the left menu or the middle pane.

[image: Screenshot Diagnose and Solve Blade]

Answer (score 0):

- Get the PID of java process from Process Explorer of Kudu (Advanced Tools)
- Use this command to collect thread dump:
  jcmd  Thread.print > D:\home\threaddump.txt